# Django | Local Bad Request (400), DEBUG=False, ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], whitenoise enabled

Tags: python, django, heroku, bad-request

I'm trying to solve that Bad Request (400) for 3 days now...
I try to deploy my first Django App, that works perfectly with DEBUG=True.

After set DEBUG to False, my troubles comes. Notice that I work locally and I use "whitenoise" to deserve images through the "staticfiles" dir, and it works nicelly (after that I want to host it on Heroku).

The strange thing is that I can acces on one URL correctly of my site and the admin without any problems....

I don't know where to search anymore... And the log said nothing that could help me, just :

#### log with py manage.py runserver

```
[15/May/2016 16:28:35] "GET /page/news HTTP/1.1" 400 26
```

#### settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print("BASE_DIR = ",BASE_DIR)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wt/static/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

SECRET_KEY = 'H-E-R-E__I-S__M-Y__K-E-Y'

DEBUG = False

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'team.apps.TeamConfig',
    'gallery.apps.GalleryConfig',
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'events.apps.EventsConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'paginator.apps.paginatorConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wt.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wt.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'wt_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'H-E-R-E__I-S__M-Y__P-W',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1',]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wt/staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wt/static'),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
CKEDITOR_BROWSE_SHOW_DIRS = True
```

#### wsgi.py

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wt.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

My head is burning, thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: You must have more error logs. Take a look at this to get those logs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see that I've a problem with my staticfiles on each page where I have wrote that :

`<img src="{% static img.thumbnail.path %}" alt="{{ img.alt}}">`

I stil have

`+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

at the end of my main **urls.py**. It looks like a problem with my MEDIA files (uploaded via Backend). How can I solve this ?

Comment: I really want to solve that yes. But I still have a problem with my staticfiles... and that is the source of my 400 errors..

Comment: Thx @Trantu, but you can't use the `static` tag inside something else than the  `{% %}`, it will cause a TemplateSyntaxError - "Could not parse the remainder"

Comment: you are right. I meant `{{ img.thumbnail.url }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gess it was a security issue. Even if "whitenoise" is good to serve true `static` files in production, it can't serve `media` files.

I was making a structure error :

```
# Don't place your 'media' files IN your 'static' file like this :

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wt/static/media/')
```

**MEDIA_ROOT** never have to be in the "static" file of your project (even if you can make it works in some ways, it's not a good practice I think).

**'MEDIA' files** (in production), have to be serve out of the Django project. I've read somewhere that we have to use a CDN. And firstly I choose CloudFlare (because it's free), but it wasn't working, cause you need a subdomain/hostname to point your MEDIA_ROOT, and CloudFlare doesn't give that. Finaly I choose Amazon S3.

So, in conclusion write something like `{% static img.thumbnail.url %}` make no sense. Because everything uploaded via admin/user haven't to be in "static".

Use `{{ img.thumbnail.url }}` instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm also getting bad request locally when debug is set to false, but I can access the Django admin fine. I'm not using the local file system to store media so I don't think I have the same problem as you. Was there another reason yours wasn't working ?